# Laravel 5.4 cannot access img resource in public symlink subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, storage, laravel-storage

I've created a sub folder for each user in local storage disk with this command:

```
if(! Storage::disk('public')->has("users/".$username."_".Auth::user()->id)){
    Storage::makeDirectory("public/users/".$username."_".Auth::user()->id);
```

and it works!

So now when i save a file, all goes in the user's folder, that is in:

```
storage/app/public/users/userX
storage/app/public/users/userY
etc.
```

Then I build a sim link with the command: `php aritsan storage:link`
And it works.

But when im trying to serve the files i've allways nothing to serve!
If im using code like:

```
Storage::url("$urlToFile");
```

where `$urlToFile` contains something like `"public/users/userX/file.png"`

it gives me back:

```
/storage/users/userX/file.png
```

and I cant use it even if i put function like `assett()` in front!

how can i solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try: `Storage::disk('local')->url($url);` ?

Comment: Which development environment are you using? Is it Homestead?

Comment: @chanafdo no im using the build-in server in a local machine, file are stored correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to set url in `config/filesystem.php`

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Comment: from my previus configuration the only differencte is the row about 'url' that now is added, but without any result!

Comment: Is APP_URL set in .env?

Comment: yes, and ive tried it with and without the port number -is http://localhost:8000-

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `Storage::disk('public')->get($url);`

Comment: Im working at the same problem: with this commands ive 2 type of result, or an empty string if I put even the "public" on the url OR a page of strange symbols if im trying without the "public" in url...  still not works!

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration), you should access your images like: `asset('storage/users/userX/file.png');`, not `public/users/userX/file.png` as you are using.

Comment: src="http://localhost:8000/users/userX/file.png" generated by both "asset() or Storage::disk('local')->url($url)" not works!

Comment: @JahStation What exactly are you passing to `asset()`?

Comment: "storage/users/USERX/FILEX.PNG"

Comment: Strange, that works for me, I get `http://localhost/storage/users/userX/file.png`

Comment: i got a port number on localhost too! could be this hte problem?